# Cannot redeclare Dayss() (previously declared in...)

Tags: php

```
Cannot redeclare Dayss() (previously declared in Y:\home\TP\www\rasp.php:180) in Y:\home\TP\www\rasp.php on line 180
```

На форумах читал, в основном эти ошибки у все возникают, из-за того, что задают имена функций, уже существующих в `php`. Но функции `Dayss` думаю нет?

```
$dayToday = date('d');
$monthToday = date('m');
$yearToday = date('Y');
function Dayss($day, $mon, $year)
 {

    $days = array("воскресенье", "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота");
    $day = (int)$day; //если день двухсимвольный и <10 
    $mon = (int)$mon; //если месяц двухсимвольный и <10 
    $a = (int)((14 - $mon) / 12);
    $y = $year - $a;
    $m = $mon + 12 * $a - 2;
    $d = (7000 + (int)($day+$y+ (int)($y/4) - (int)($y/100) + (int)($y/400) + (31*$m)/12))%7;
    return $days[$d];
    }
echo Dayss($dayToday, $monthToday, $yearToday);
 }
```

Comment: `rasp.php` подключаете с помощью `include` или `require` несколько раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Походу вы где-то два раза вашу функцию объявляете или проблема может возникнуть из-за буферизации. **Решение:**

```
if(!function_exists('Dayss')) {
  function Dayss($day, $mon, $year){

    $days = array("воскресенье", "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота");
    $day = (int)$day; //если день двухсимвольный и <10 
    $mon = (int)$mon; //если месяц двухсимвольный и <10 
    $a = (int)((14 - $mon) / 12);
    $y = $year - $a;
    $m = $mon + 12 * $a - 2;
    $d = (7000 + (int)($day+$y+ (int)($y/4) - (int)($y/100) + (int)($y/400) + (31*$m)/12))%7;
    return $days[$d];
    }
echo Dayss($dayToday, $monthToday, $yearToday);
 }
}
```